# How To Add Additional Methods To Standard CRUD Spring JPA Repository Methods Using @Query (e.g. Search By Name, Role, Category)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am using Spring JPA Repository to create a SpringBoot Spring MVC CRUD REST backend service which connects to my MySQL database. Its basically a user management module with login screen - user Id, user name, user password and user role. After extending the Spring JPA Repository, with the standard Spring JPA CRUD methods (getOne, getById, findAll, findById, etc), I want to add another two custom methods in my repository called getUserByName and getUserByRole using custom SQL queries which will return a List, Collection or HashMap as it may be multiple records. An auto-generated Id serves as the primary key and I have indexed also my User Names and User Roles fields in the user table.

My code is as shown below :

User table CREATE SQL :

```
CREATE TABLE `t_user_ms` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_name` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
    `user_email` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
    `user_password` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
    `user_role` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
    `user_tel_no` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
    `login_date_time` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `entry_date_time` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `update_date_time` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `get_users` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `user_name` (`user_name`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `user_role` (`user_role`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=12
;
```

User Class (User.java) :

```
package com.fsgsm.kilosteprest.model;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

//import javax.persistence.Entity;
//import javax.persistence.Table;
//import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
//import javax.persistence.Id;

import javax.persistence.*;


@Entity
@Table(name = "T_USER_MS")
public class User {
    
    
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    
    private String userName;
    private String userPassword;
    private String userTelNo;
    private String userEmail;
    private String userRole;
    private LocalDateTime loginDateTime;
    private LocalDateTime entryDateTime;
    private LocalDateTime updateDateTime;



    //constructor
    public User () {
        this.userName = "";
        this.userPassword = "";
        this.userTelNo = "";
        this.userEmail = "";
        this.userRole = "";
        this.loginDateTime = null;
        this.entryDateTime = null;
        this.updateDateTime = null;
    }
    
    
    
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    public String getUserPassword() {
        return userPassword;
    }
    public void setUserPassword(String userPassword) {
        this.userPassword = userPassword;
    }
    public String getUserTelNo() {
        return userTelNo;
    }
    public void setUserTelNo(String userTelNo) {
        this.userTelNo = userTelNo;
    }
    public String getUserEmail() {
        return userEmail;
    }
    public void setUserEmail(String userEmail) {
        this.userEmail = userEmail;
    }
    public String getUserRole() {
        return userRole;
    }
    public void setUserRole(String userRole) {
        this.userRole = userRole;
    }
    public LocalDateTime getLoginDateTime() {
        return loginDateTime;
    }
    public void setLoginDateTime(LocalDateTime loginDateTime) {
        this.loginDateTime = loginDateTime;
    }
    public LocalDateTime getEntryDateTime() {
        return entryDateTime;
    }
    public void setEntryDateTime(LocalDateTime entryDateTime) {
        this.entryDateTime = entryDateTime;
    }
    public LocalDateTime getUpdateDateTime() {
        return updateDateTime;
    }
    public void setUpdateDateTime(LocalDateTime updateDateTime) {
        this.updateDateTime = updateDateTime;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "Table T_USER_MS user";
    }
    
}
```

User Service Implementation (UserServiceImpl.java)

```
package com.fsgsm.kilosteprest.service.impl;


import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.fsgsm.kilosteprest.service.UserService;
import com.fsgsm.kilosteprest.repository.UserRepository;
import com.fsgsm.kilosteprest.model.User;


@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    
    
    @Autowired
    UserRepository dao;
 
    @Override
    public User addNewUser(User user) {
        return dao.save(user);
    }
    @Override
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return dao.findAll();
    }
    @Override
    public User getUserById(int userId) {
        return dao.getOne(userId);
    }
    @Override
    public User updateUser(User user) {
        return dao.save(user);
    }
    @Override
    public void deleteUserById(int userId) {
        dao.deleteById(userId);
    }
    @Override
    public void deleteAllUsers() {
        dao.deleteAll();
    }

    

    //get users list by user name
   public List<User> getUsersByuserName(String usrName) {
            
        return (List<User>)dao.getUsersByuserName(usrName);
    }


    //get users list by user role
   public List<User> getUsersByuserRole(String usrRole) {
            
        return (List<User>)dao.getUsersByuserRole(usrRole);
    }


}
```

In my repository, I add the custom methods with a @Query to accomodate my custom SQL queries for the two new methods (search by name, role) as below :

Spring Repository (UserRepository.java) :

```
package com.fsgsm.kilosteprest.repository;


import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
//import org.springframework.data.repository.Repository;
import com.fsgsm.kilosteprest.model.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;


@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
    
    public User addNewUser(User user);
    public User updateUser(User user);
    public void deleteUserById(int userId);
    public void deleteAllUsers();
    public List<User> getUsers();
    public User getUserById(int userId);
    
    
    //new custom query - search by name 
    @Query(nativeQuery=true, value="SELECT u.* FROM t_user_ms u WHERE u.userName =: name")
    public List<User> getUsersByuserName(String name);


    //new custom query - search by role
    @Query(nativeQuery=true, value="SELECT u.* FROM t_user_ms u WHERE u.userRole =: role")
    public List<User> getUsersByuserRole(String role);


}
```

The problem is I am getting the following error(s) from the console:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[2m2021-01-28 02:40:57.490[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m16048[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.boot.SpringApplication              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'service'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.fsgsm.kilosteprest.repository.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.fsgsm.kilosteprest.repository.UserRepository.getUsers()! No property getUsers found for type User!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1415) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:608) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:923) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:588) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1311) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at com.fsgsm.kilosteprest.KilosteprestApplication.main(KilosteprestApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.fsgsm.kilosteprest.repository.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.fsgsm.kilosteprest.repository.UserRepository.getUsers()! No property getUsers found for type User!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1415) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:608) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.fsgsm.kilosteprest.repository.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.fsgsm.kilosteprest.repository.UserRepository.getUsers()! No property getUsers found for type User!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:609) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.fsgsm.kilosteprest.repository.UserRepository.getUsers()! No property getUsers found for type User!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:96) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:107) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:218) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:81) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:100) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1056) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:85) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:258) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:85) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:303) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$6(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:326) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:230) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:329) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1847) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1784) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    ... 48 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property getUsers found for type User!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:90) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:437) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:413) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.lambda$from$0(PropertyPath.java:366) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:330) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:348) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:331) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:249) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:250) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:383) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:384) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:92) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:89) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    ... 74 common frames omitted
```

How do I add these two additional custom methods to the standard queries already present in Spring JPA repository using @Query ?

Comment: Why you are defining the six methods (e. g. `getUserById`, in other words: the methods that are not annotated with `Query` and provided by `JpaRepository`(-hierarchy) automatically) in the repository? Did you try to comment them out?

Comment: What does the `User` class look like? The error is "No property getUsers found for type User!"

Comment: @RobertBain, I've added my User class above.

Comment: @hjoeren, yes  you are right! When  I commented out the  six methods (e. g. getUserById, in other words: the methods that are not annotated with Query and provided by JpaRepository(-hierarchy) automatically) in the repository, the whole program works and starts running again without errors! Thanks hjoren !

Answer (score 1):

The problem its your **getUsers**() method.

Your two custom methods with a @Query are ok.

Only change the name of your method getUsers(), and should be works.

```
public List<User> getUsers();
```

maybe to

```
public List<User> findAll();
```

or
remove it.

- JPA supports findAll() by default.